# Boost Variant : How can I do a visitor that returns the type that was set?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

I'm trying to write a generic map that uses a boost:variant as the value.
I'm stuck on trying to write the get(std::string key) function that will return the appropriate type.

Here is what I came up with so far:

```
 class GenericHashMap {
private:
std::map< std::string, boost::variant<int, bool, double, std::string> > genericMap;

public:
  template<typename T>
  bool getValue(const std::string & key, T & value) {
     if ( _map.find(key) == _map.end() ) {
        return false;
     }
     T * valuePtr = boost::get<T>(_map[key]);
     if (valuePtr == NULL) {
        return false;
     }
     value = *valuePtr;
     return true;
  }
}
```

I'm curious how I should handle iterators? Is it worth making my own nested iterators or just return the nested std::map.

**Edit**

I added the class design I was hoping to achieve (i.e. a generic hashmap). The problem I had was that I wanted a way for the user to query if for a specific key it was stored as a specific type.

Comment: The visitor can return NULL if it is of the wrong type!

Comment: `boost::get` is not a visitor.

Comment: What are you trying to do that a just a map of `boost::variant` doesn't already do?

Comment: I want the map to return the specific type if that's what was set for the key. i.e. if someone set a key "hello" to an unsigned int I want to make sure that trying to set it to a std::string is incorrect.

Comment: How do you intend to use this function excatly? (Describe with some (pseudo)code, not words.)

Comment: @IgorR. I added some more context

Answer (score 1):

If you have such an issue, it probably means you should use a visitor instead of wanting to get the value out of your variant. It is usually the way to go with `boost::variant`.

If you think about it: you do not want to hardwire a specific type for a specific key value. Otherwise, it means you lose all the power of `boost::variant`. And it means you should have different maps for each key sets (as you know them statically, you should not put everything in the same map).

`boost::variant` is really here to help you with dynamic dispatch, not static branching.

**Note**: In your example you lookup your item twice when it is found, you should store the result of `find` instead of discarding it, saving you the second lookup.

Comment: I'm confused on how to write my visitor for such a use case. I'd like the visitor to return the value of the template I'd specify or NULL? When someone is trying to assign the variant to a certain type I want to make sure the map was stored using the type they expect?

Comment: What I am saying is that the error lies in the design: you should not want that. Think about your root issue instead of trying to circumvent it. You are mixing dynamic runtime information and static information: it cannot work. Either you statically have multiples maps, or you accept that the type inside your variant is dynamic. You cannot have both: that's what the C++ typing system enforces.